# In C, can an address of a pointer be 0?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm reading the solution to a problem in the book [Cracking the Coding interview](http://www.crackingthecodinginterview.com/) (Q 1.2). The objective there is to implement a function `void revers(char* str)` in C that reverses a null terminating string.

The solution code looks something like this:

```
void reverse(char *str)
{
   char* end=str;
   char tmp;
   if(str)
   {
       while(*end)
       {
          end++;
       }
       end--;
       //code to reverse
   }
}
```

Here, `str` contains an address right? And `if(str)` will only evaluate to `false` if `str` is `0`, right?

So what I'm saying is, is there no chance that `str` will contain the address `0x0000`, thus evaluating `if(str)` to `false`?

Comment: Can I refer you to an answer of mine [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462299/initializing-variable-at-address-zero-in-c/17462496#17462496) regarding a similar question?

Comment: Not unless you yourself pass `str` as zero to the function.

Comment: Run this: `char *p; printf("%p", p);` to answer your question. :)

Comment: @ludesign Ah, the joy of undefined behavior...

Comment: why not: `reverse(0)`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Its better to assume that you aren't going to be the only person calling your functions when you write them.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - Yes; but compiled with GCC will null it. :)

Comment: @ludesign Even if a single compiler does it in some situations, unspecified behavior is by definition unspecified and should not be trusted upon.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - true! Never said the opposite. However my comment was just for fun, nothing more. :)

Answer (score 15):

`str` does indeed contain an address (it's a pointer to `char`), and `if(str)` will evaluate to false *iff the `str` is equal to the null pointer*.

Note that the null pointer is not required by the standard to refer to address `0`; however, the standard mandates that a *literal value* of `0` when used in a pointer context must be interpreted by the compiler as the address of the null pointer -- whatever that might be.

This means that the test `if(p == 0)` is guaranteed to always be the same as `if(p == NULL)`. Also, the conditional `if(p)` is guaranteed to always be the same as `if(p != 0)`.

Conclusion: your code will always detect a null pointer, *but* that's not technically the same as a pointer that points to address zero (even though in practice you are going to find that it usually is).

Answer (score 5):

```
if(str)
```

is equivalent with

```
if(str != NULL)
```

or

```
if(str != 0)
```

This test is not to test whether `str` has an address of `0`, it tests whether `str` is a null pointer.

Note that a null pointer doesn't have to have an address `0`, the standard only ensures that a null pointer is unequal to any other non-null pointers.

C11 6.3.2.3 *Pointers*

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
>   void *, is called a null pointer constant.66) If a null pointer constant is converted to a
>   pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically 0x0 pointer is valid, but all nowadays compiler won't give you virtual address 0, because it is reserved to represent null pointer (pointer to nothing).

Some kernels could be still using it, but unless you are writing something very low level in very uncommon kernels you could assume that 0x0 is not pointing to any memory.

NULL constant was created for value for pointer not pointing anything. Now NULL has always value 0.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such chance, **unless you pass a `NULL` pointer** to the function.

In C there was no boolean type until it has been introduced in C99. Any logic operations (including conditionals) check a value against zero, regardless its real type.

Comment: How do you know that `reverse()` is not called with a 0-pointer?

Comment: Of course, I mean if you pass a valid pointer. I will fix an answer to clarify.

Comment: Ooops, it seems that I misunderstood the question. Sorry for that.

Comment: in C99 boolean type was introduced

Answer (score 2):

> So what I'm saying is, is there no chance that str will contain the address 0x0000, thus evaluating if(str) to false?

Yes, there is: in case you are calling `reverse()` with a null pointer, it will evaluate to false.

This is used as a safety net, in case it happens that `reverse()` is called with a null pointer, so that the code does not access invalid memory when actually reversing the string.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking should I test for someone passing NULL pointers in my function then the answer is YES.

Comment: I disagree. It's not the function responsibility to check whether it gets valid parameter or not. If someone made a "wrong call" by passing a `NULL` pointer, well, let the program crash. Of course, this heavily depends on context, so it may not apply to the poster's situation.

Comment: @Xaqq it would depend on whether the function was intended to be called directly by other programmers or serves only as an internal helper function. When in doubt err on the side of caution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible if `str` is a NULL pointer on any architecture which have reserved address `0x000` for `null pointer`.

Answer (score 1):

`if(str)` is added to check whether str has allocated memory or not. Best practice is to initialize a pointer to `NULL` when it is declared.

the above is equal to

```
if(str != NULL)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here, str contains an address right?

Yes. It is a `char *`. Its value represents an address of a `char`.

> And if(str) will only evaluate to false if str is 0, right?

Yes.

> is there no chance that str will contain the address 0x0000, thus
>   evaluating if(str) to false?

This is perfectly possible. Just call the function with this value.

```
char * myCharPointer = 0;
reverse(myCharPointer);
```

I never use this style, though. I prefer to use NULL, which is guaranteed by the C standard to be equivalent. I prefer NULL because it is more expressive and it helps to separate ordinary integer values from addresses.

```
char * myCharPointer = NULL;
reverse(myCharPointer);
```

See also these related questions:

- [C: Comparison to NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1284050/96780)
- [Is NULL in C required/defined to be zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8288482/96780).

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
if (str)
```

is equivalent to

```
if (str != 0)
```

which in turn is interpreted by the compiler as

```
if (str != null-pointer-value-for-char-pointer-type)
```

I.e. it has nothing to do with "address zero" at all. The compiler is required to recognize the pointer context and perform comparison with the implementation-dependent null-pointer value for type `char *`. The latter will be represented physically by an implementation-dependent address value, not necessarily zero address.