# argc and argv in C

Tags: c, argv, argc

Suppose I have this example function

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

        char* pChar = argv[2]; // Get the second argument "Word"
        char * pAdd = pChar + strlen(pChar); // 0 + 5
}
```

and run by inputting **./fileName Hello World**

Since argv[2] = World, pChar should point to the memory address of the Char "World"

However, what I don't get is why pChar = 0 (that is what the book says) when executing **pChar + strlen(pChar)** line of code.

Comment: *However, what I don't get is why pChar = 0 when executing pChar + strlen(pChar) line of code.*  How do you know `pChar` is `0`?

Comment: Did you mean `*pAdd` to be *0*?

Comment: Because the string is just "World" and C strings are terminated by a 0. What did you expect it to be?

Comment: "the book" - what book?  Run the code, see for yourself.  The book either has a typo, or you are misreporting what it says.

Answer (score 2):

pChar is not `0`.

**POSSIBLE ERROR:** `*pAdd` is **0** instead of `pChar` since `pAdd` is pointing to the last character of string `"World"` i.e. `'\0'` and integral value of null termination (`'\0'`) is **0**.

You want to say that address is **0** - you might need to read about that:

[in c can an address of a pointer be 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783029/in-c-can-an-address-of-a-pointer-be-0)

Answer (score 1):

You need to explain or demonstrate how you made the observation. `pChar` will not be zero, however it will point to the NUL *character* at the end of the second argument.  i.e `*pChar` will be NUL - demonstrated by the empty string pointed to by `pAdd` here:

[image]

The upshot is, make your observations using a debugger - it is the least intrusive method and does not rely on you writing *debug code* correctly.